# Has God made ALL the animals dwelling on earth?

Tags: creation

Is it possible for other angels/entities, even malevolent as satan, to have made living creatures?

Comment: One can make a golem,however one has to use materials that were created from Hashem

Comment: Animals make animals all the time.

Comment: Yea but using materials of the world that have been created.  Nothing new is under the sun...

Comment: Are you asking about the myth that Satan is somehow rebellious with free will or *created* something independently or against the will of Hashem?

Comment: maybe related https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.6.4

Answer (score 5):

According to Mishna Torah, laws and foundations of the Torah, 1:1-3

eng. trans.: "The foundations of all foundations and pillar of all wisdom is to know that there is One G-d who brought into being all existence. All beings of the heavens and the earth and what is between them came into existence only from the Truth of HaShem's Being."

Seems like the rambam thought there wasn't any other Creator but HaShem, I trust this.

Comment: ה׳ אלקינו ה׳ **אחד**

Comment: Wasn’t correcting you. On that last point of trusting the Rambam, just pointing out where he got it from.

Comment: @DonielF thanks, makes it a better answer even.

Comment: Its from the Shma, right? @DonielF

Comment: Yes. Devarim 6:4.